# Synchronously go through Flink DataStream[String], but asynchronously do multiple updates to each message

Tags: scala, apache-flink, future

```
val updatedDataStream = dataStream.map(new MyMapFunction)
```

I use map() instead of Flink's native AsyncDataStream because I want to go through the messages synchronously. AsyncDataStream.unorderedWait or orderedWait will go through the message asynchronously.

Below code, updates each message in the dataStream with 2 updates, but the 2 updates are done asynchronously so the total time of both updates together is equal to the time taken by the slowest update.

```
class MyMapFunction extends RichMapFunction[String, String]{

  private var client: AsyncClient = _

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    client = new AsyncClient
  }

  override def map(value: String): String = {
    if (value.nonEmpty) {
      // below line de-serializes json message to an parsable object
      val a = objectMapper.readValue(value, classOf[Test])

      // below function calls (firstUpdate and secondUpdate) return back Future[String]
      val firstFieldValue = client.firstUpdate()
      val secondFieldValue = client.secondUpdate()

      def updateRecord(r1: String, r2: String): String = {
        a.firstField = r1
        a.secondField = r2
        // below line serializes object back to a json String
        objectMapper.writeValueAsString(a)
      }

      val enrichment = for {
        r1 <- firstFieldValue
        r2 <- secondFieldValue
      } yield (updateRecord(r1, r2))

      val f = enrichment.onComplete {
        case Success(result) => result
        case Failure(exception) => exception
      }

    } else ""
  }

}
```

Problem:
This won't work as `onComplete` returns `Unit`. But I want it to return `result` (String) so I can send it back to `updatedDataStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `map` has a synchronous signature, you'll have to block.  `Await.result` blocks until the future completes.

```scala
// instead of val f = enrichment.onComplete ...
Await.result(enrichment, Duration.Inf)
```

Note that blocking like this may limit throughput, though if `r1` and `r2` are able to execute in parallel, this period of blocking will likely be shorter than the time the thread invoking `map` would be blocked if done synchronously.

Comment: Thanks for a possible solution Levi Ramsey. But why do you say it will limit the throughput? I am anyways doing a map, which means only once both the updates of one message finish will the map go to the next message. So Await shouldn't affect the throughput at all. Right?

Comment: In this particular case, it's almost certainly ok.  I put it in there's more of a disclaimer that using `Await`, especially in something that uses Akka under the hood like Flink, can get very unpredictable quickly.

Comment: Blocking in Flink user functions is an anti-pattern, and can lead to job failures. This is because you are blocking the main task thread, and preventing checkpoints from progressing, timers from firing, etc. E.g., I've seen cases where it seems ok 99% of the time, but then blows up every time the external resource is under heavy load.

Comment: If Await is not recommended then is there a better way to handle this requirement?

Comment: Not really.  You can't fight the type signatures.  The most you might be able to do is pipe the result of the future into a stream that Flink can subscribe to (e.g. produce to a Kafka topic).  Then you've effectively introduced the asychronous boundary you want.